# best way to make a page can only be accessed from an another page

Tags: php

what is the best way to make a page can only be accessed from an another page. (e.g: step2 page can only be accessed from step 1 page)

I thought about several methods such as:

use form submit from step1 to step2, in step 2 need to check post data

check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, allow if the referer is step 1

Comment: What have you tried apart from that because the referrer can be spoofed so it is not much help. Also accepts some answers on previous questions

Comment: Don't rely on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. It's something the client sends and not all browsers send it. It can be easily manipulated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sessions is the only possible way.

```
if ($_SESSION['step'] <> 2) {
   // do something terrible (c) Cousin Avi
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Submitting a POST form is probably the best way.